# cypher query to get middle objects in traversal and shortest path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Can't seem to figure out, and I'm not sure it entirely possible. I have a graph like so

```
 a-[:granted]->b-[:granted]->...x-[granted_source]>s
```

where b and x are of interest. While I already know a and s, the end points, which are defined in START clause.

Note that b and c could be one `( a->b->s )` or more then one `( a->b->c->x->s )` and the goal is to find the shortest path returning only the nodes that are pointed to by a 'granted' relationship.

The closest I've got is:

```
start s=node(21), p=node(2)
match paths=shortestPath(p-[:granted|granted_source*]->s)
return NODES(paths)
```

Which gives all the nodes, including start (p) and end (s). But I can't seem to filter out, or better would be to not return them at all, only the nodes that are pointed to by a granted relationship and in the order from (s) if possible. I'm on Neo4j 2.0b and I'm wondering if Labels, which I have no issue using, would be the better way to go? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Just to check, it's not the case that only the last relationship is of type `[granted_source]` in your model? You have patterns like `b-[:granted_source]->c-[:granted]->d-[:granted_source]->s` as well?

Comment: Yes, only the last is granted_source, and there could be many from x other s's (in my very first example), so ```a-[:granted]->b-[:granted]->...x-[granted_source]>s1``` or ```a-[:granted]->b-[:granted]->...x-[granted_source]>s2```. Hope that answers your question jjaderberg?

Comment: Probably makes little difference in your case, but `-[granted|granted_source*]->` is infinite depth with any combination and order of the two relationships. `-[granted*]->x-[granted_source]->` better expresses the pattern you're querying for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you want to chop the head and tail off of a collection of nodes? (Am I understanding that right?) How about:

```
start s=node(21), p=node(2)
match paths=shortestPath(p-[:granted|granted_source*]->s)
return NODES(paths)[1..-1]
```

Comment: Both my solution and yours seem to take the same amount of time (caveat: basic test with the browser console). Well I learnt something new, and I'm more keen on your shorter solution. You win! ... for now! ;)

Comment: Wes, can you link where you found the [1..-1] ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I resolved it using a WITH, I think this is probably the best performance given that first the p-... are fetched, then all ...->s are fetched and then using the shortestPath() is used to get the 'in between' nodes. The results appear correct.

```
start s=node(21), p=node(2)
match p-[:granted]-x, y-[:granted_source]->s
with x, y
match paths=shortestPath(x-[:granted*]->y)
return NODES(paths)
```